# Cookie for a refresh-token is not stored

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, session-cookies, refresh-token

I'm currently struggling with JWT and refresh tokens. I implemented the [following flow](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-1.5) from the OAuth 2 spec.

The user gets a JWT token which is used for requests and before it expires with the refresh token a new JWT is retrieved.

It works fine, the refresh token is properly returned by the API, but not stored in the cookies storage of the browser. The request for obtaining the token are using `{ withCredentials: true }`

The way how the user gets the refresh token looks like the following. The web app runs on example1.com and the API server on example2.com, both run with https. Is there a error in my cookie configuration or some other mistake in my code?

```
  const cookieOptions = {
    httpOnly: true,
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
    secure: true,
    sameSite: 'none',
  };
  res.cookie('refresh_token', token, cookieOptions);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your connection using http or https? You have defined `secure: true` which means the browser will not send your cookie with the secure attribute set over an unencrypted HTTP request

Comment: The connection is using https

Answer (score 0):

The cookie will be considered third party and browsers drop these aggressively. Aim to convert this to a first party cookie instead, via these steps:

- Web app origin is https://www.example.com
- API runs at https://api.example.com - a sibling domain
- Cookie domain is `.example.com`

This kind of domain relationship is a prerequisite to using secure cookies these days, due to recent browser restrictions to prevent tracking. I expect your code will work fine once the domain setup is correct.

For further info see this [Curity Code Example](https://github.com/curityio/web-oauth-via-bff) and the use of a hosts file to test the domain setup. This example also encrypts the cookie using AES256 and uses the cookie setting `SameSite=strict`.

Comment: The thing is that the api server runs on example2.com and not on a subdomain of example1.com. How to manage that?

Comment: There is a hosting prerequisite for cookies issued by APIs to work for a web origin -.due to recent browser restrictions to prevent tracking. None of us can write code that works if these prerequisites are not met.

Comment: what about running on localhost?  how can you test it's working correctly if you can't check locally

Comment: Localhost URLs should also work, eg `http://localhost:3000` for the web app, and `http://localhost:3001` for the API. This does not prepare you well for proper deployments though, which will use domain names and SSL. The [code example doc](https://github.com/curityio/web-oauth-via-bff/blob/main/doc/Standard.md) shows how to use real world domains on any development computer, via the hosts file. You can then use local URLs such as `http://www.example.com` and `http://api.example.com:3000`, and these are in the same site.